# Magento Mobile Images

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, mobile

I am using Magento 1.7.2 and the desktop site is fine. How on the mobile its taking to long to load because I have images on the home page of the site. I have the desktop site themed (mytheme) and I also see the iphone theme for mobile. Is there a way to tell the mobile phone not to load images from the home page?

You can see the desktop site here: http://www.webstertoolbox.com

Answer (score 1):

I just accessed the site via a mobile (ios and android) and it looks to me like the mobile device are also loading the full site.

Did you configure the themes to use for mobiles in the admin?

system->configuration->design

If it helps, I have a module on github that I maintain that configures this section

https://github.com/ProxiBlue/MobileUpdates